# JQuery tablesorter, <table> in <table> (nested tables)

Tags: javascript, html-table, nested, tablesorter

I have a table filled with data from a database. This table is sortable thanks to jQuery tablesorter. My issue is that one of the cell of the main table contain two other tables. So sort on the main table doesn't work anymore. How can I force the sort only on the main table?

Here a sample of my table' source code after recovering the other table from my database:

```
<table id='users' class='tablesorter' width='100%' border='0'>
  <thead> ... </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even">
      <td> ... </td>
      <td> ... </td>
      <td>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellsapcing="0" width="907"
          <tbody>
            <tr class="even"> ... </tr>
            <tr class="even"> ... </tr>
            <tr class="even"> ... </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellsapcing="0" width="907"
          <tbody>
            <tr class="even"> ... </tr>
            <tr class="even"> ... </tr>
            <tr class="even"> ... </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
       ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My javascript :

```
$("#users").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: {
            sorter: false
        },
        4: {
            sorter: false
        },
        5: {
            sorter: false
        },
        6: {
            sorter: false
        },
        7: {
            sorter: false
        },
        9: {
            sorter: false
        },
        10: {
            sorter: false
        },
        11: {
            sorter: false
        },
        12: {
            sorter: false
        },
        13: {
            sorter: false
        },
        14: {
            sorter: false
        },
        15: {
            sorter: false
        }
    }
}).bind("sortEnd",function() {
$(this).find('tbody tr:odd').removeClass('odd even').addClass('odd');
$(this).find('tbody tr:even').removeClass('odd even').addClass('even');
}).trigger("sortEnd");
```

My css :

```
.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: white;
}
.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an issue that exists with the original version of tablesorter . Nested tables are not properly isolated ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1370/)).

Check out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which does pay particular attention to nested tables. Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/560/).

```
$(function () {
    $('#main').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra']
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but in your demo, what i need is that grades column is sortable and this column contain normal text and on one cell contains two tables. The presence of the two tables on one cell involve the non sorting of my column, the <tr> tags existing on my database became automatically <tr class="even"> and the sort stop working on this column :/

Comment: I don't have the time to modify the demo, so try it on your site... initialize tablesorter using `$('table')` instead of `$('#main')`.

Comment: Finally, the problem was not the nested table but the fact that one of the cell of the nested table contains a date. I know that I can make it working if all the column always contains a date, but in my table the content is random, so how can I make the date working properly with tablesort ?